# How to create laptop backups that can be restored to a bootable virtual machine

Tags: backup, virtualization, deja-dup

Is there some way to configure Déjà Dup to create backups of a laptop to a server, such that the the most recent backup can be restored directly to (a bootable) virtual machine if the laptop is lost (or stolen)?

If not via Déjà Dup, then perhaps some other backup tool?

( I recall this is easy to do with Symantec Ghost on windows. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tools that allow for so-called *bare metal restore*, Acronis TrueImage is one of them and I'm pretty sure you'll find more.

Using these tools, you can restore the image to a virtual machine, but be aware:
You system might not be in the state you'd expect it to be, since you boot the system on other (virtual) hardware.